# Regular expression to match z1 or z2 in Ocaml

Tags: regex, ocaml

How to write regular expressions in ocaml?

How can I write a regular expression for `"z1" + "z2"` (z1 or z2) ?

I tried this way, but it is giving me errors.

```
let p = Str.regexp "("z1")|("z2")";;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend to match double quotes in your input you should escape them:

```
"(\\"z1\\")\\|(\\"z2\\")"
```

And you can shorten the alternation using `z1|z2`:

```
"(\\"z1\\|z2\\")"
```

Otherwise, if double quotes aren't part of the input, the pattern should be:

```
"(z1\\|z2)"
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like maybe he doesn't want the double quotes to be in the pattern.  Also you need to escape the `|` to get the special meaning of alternation.  So then the pattern is `"z1\\|z2"`.  It's true that the lexical conventions of strings interfere with the RE notation a bit.

Comment: @Jeffrey thanks for the feedback. Updated to reflect both scenarios and escape the alternation metacharacter.